# Create date variable for dbGetQuery in R?

Tags: mysql, sql, r

basically this is the start of my query/code:

```
dbGetQuery(con,'SELECT user_id, unique_id
where order_date > parse_datetime('2021-11-01')')
```

(took out a load because this gets the point across).

The query is quite long and uses the date from above a good few times.
So I was wondering if I can create a variable and replace the date.

Something in the format:

```
date_variable <- 2021-11-01

dbGetQuery(con,'SELECT user_id, unique_id
where order_date > parse_datetime('date_variable')')
```

I am very new to R and don't really know what I'm doing so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: use double quotes around your query, since you are using single quotes inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I prefer to use `glue` package for this:

```
library(glue)
library(DBI)

date_variable <- as.Date("2021-11-01")

query <- glue_sql("SELECT user_id, unique_id where order_date > parse_datetime({date_variable})",
         date_variable = date_variable,
         .con = con)

dbGetQuery(con, query)
```

This source can be interesting for you: [Run Queries Safely](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having a bit of a problem though! When I use dbGetQuery, I have to put dates in this format: parse_datetime(\'2021-11-01\') otherwise it doesn't seem to work. So when I save that query and input the variable - it comes out in the format: parse_datetime(''2021-11-01''). Those are two single quotes by the way. And it doesn't include the forward dash which is why I think the query isn't working when I run it. Any advice on this? Thanks again